# duplication record found on the same system used at different location

Tags: php

I have a weird case found in my web-based system and I couldn't find out what is the reason behind this.

I have a web-based system, and it has been used at 2 different companies. One company doesn't have any problem while using the system, with good internet connection. But the other company have double record while saving each of the transaction, with poorer internet connection.

For ex:
A user add a record for customer with name Helen. When the information is filled up, user clicks the save button. After saving, the 2nd company will find 2 records with same customer, which is Helen. This problem is occurred sometimes, not happen to all data entry.

I'm not really sure about the real process on how they save the data, but according to the company staff they sometimes get this problem.

What will be the reason behind this duplication record? Is it related to the internet connection? or there is a problem with my system?

Comment: How can we know? You mean duplicated entry in DB ? Show us related codes & DB table schema .

Comment: I mean duplication when add a data. For ex. when the users want to add a customer with name Helen. when the data is saved, record shows there are 2 data inserted with same name.

Comment: Your question doesn't really help us find out what the problem is. You may want to describe what you have searched for, if the problem is stable (meaning that the 2nd company ALWAYS produces the same results) etc. It could be as simple as a non-experienced user hitting refresh every time your site loads for more than 3 seconds...

Comment: @Verlee you haven't shared any single line of code and expecting result from us. how ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before adding a new record , you might want to make sure another record does not already exist with ( probably exact or ) similar info .

If there is a column in which you would not want to expect any duplicates , you could consider that column to check if the new value already exists and then not to add a duplicate record . And if needed show appropriate message to the user that info is added .

Harder way would be to check more than one column or may be all columns considering if there aren't too many .

Irrespective of weather it is due to issue with internet connection or users refreshing the page , where ever possible **it is always good to include code not to allow duplicates** unless it is a requirement .

Comment: I see...I guess that will be another solution to solve this problem. Actually the duplication checking has been provided in the form when the user keys in the customer name. However, I think something is happened during the saving record into the database, ex. user click on the refresh button when the page is loading.

Comment: Even if the form input is validated in the browser , in any case it is always good to totally validate the form input on the server side just before putting it to use and especially when Inserting/Updating in to a database table **.**